# Retrieving JSON with WinJS.xhr():

Tags: php, javascript, json, windows-runtime

I have having trouble with retrieving chatmessages in winjs.xhr:

```
  function getMessage() {
        var time = MESSAGE_RETURNED.unixtime;
        if (time == 0) {
            time= window.parent.SESSION.unixtime;
        }

        WinJS.xhr({
            url: "http://www.example.com/scripts/default.php?"
               + "action="+ACTIONS.GET_MESSAGE
               + "&username=" + window.parent.SESSION.username
               + "&session_id=" + window.parent.SESSION.session_id
               + "&unixtime=" + time
        }).done(
           function fulfilled(result) {
               console.log("action=" + ACTIONS.GET_MESSAGE
               + "&username=" + window.parent.SESSION.username
               + "&session_id=" + window.parent.SESSION.session_id
               + "&unixtime=" + time);//CHECK INPUTS , ALL GREEN

               if (result.status === 200) {

                   if (result.response.toString.length === 0) {
                       return false;
                   }//ALWAYS TRUE;
                   else {
                       console.log(JSON.parse(result.response));

                  }
               } else {
                   document.getElementById("messagelogarea").value += result.status + "\r\n";
               }
           });
    }
```

I am trying to retrive JSON from php. However, the response I give back is always null when using WinJS.xhr. If put the direct link in my browser, i will have results like this:
(an array which contains 3 chat messages)

```
{
    "message": [
        {
            "_id": "428",
            "from_TBonlineusers_id": "00477",
            "fromTBonlineusers_username": "GUEST_477",
            "fromTBonlineusers_type": "GUEST",
            "messagetype": "PUBLIC",
            "message": "wat?xxwiii",
            "chatmessagetime": "2012-11-16 15:36:06",
            "unixtime": "1353098166"
        },
        {
            "_id": "429",
            "from_TBonlineusers_id": "00477",
            "fromTBonlineusers_username": "GUEST_477",
            "fromTBonlineusers_type": "GUEST",
            "messagetype": "PUBLIC",
            "message": "wat?xxwiii",
            "chatmessagetime": "2012-11-16 15:42:42",
            "unixtime": "1353098562"
        },
        {
            "_id": "430",
            "from_TBonlineusers_id": "00477",
            "fromTBonlineusers_username": "GUEST_477",
            "fromTBonlineusers_type": "GUEST",
            "messagetype": "PUBLIC",
            "message": "wat?xxwiiir",
            "chatmessagetime": "2012-11-16 15:42:48",
            "unixtime": "1353098568"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: First things first, have you granted your application access to the internet in your appxmanifest?

Comment: Are you calling the serverside page from the same domain/subdomain? [Answer either validates or invalidates my solution.]

Comment: Yes. I am only using one domain.

Comment: When you look at the response that comes back from the server [fiddler, firebug, etc], does it look correct? You should also be encoding the querystring values.

Comment: The 2nd code block in this page is the response I am getting if I entered in broswer. which is correct. php:echo json_encode($returningData);

Comment: You have `result.response.toString.length`.  Should it not be `result.response.toString().length`?

Comment: Your right. however visual studio didn't complain, in fact it was done by content assist.

Comment: @Kyle can you put that to the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toString` is a method of most objects.

Your line `result.response.toString.length` should be `result.response.toString().length`